# Javascript - Display date time and ignore locale/timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, dayjs

I am having a bit of a nightmare working with a CMS that saves datetimes without timezones. For a wide variety of infrastructure reasons **I am unable to adjust core files**, I can only adjust some of the javascript of the CMS field itself, and not include external libraries (or the dayjs UTC plugin).

**How it currently works:**

1. CMS Saves datetime string like so: `2020-10-29 05:00` which is missing the timezone
2. When reloading, the dayjs parses the string `2020-10-29 05:00` as `UTC` and changes the time based on the browser locale.
3. If you are using a browser that it not UTC, the time displayed will not correspond to the saved string

**My hacky idea:**

1. When loading the string, get the browser's timezone
2. Modify the string `2020-10-29 05:00` to include the browser's timezone, or offset the date object so that when it is parsed as 'local', it will display correctly

My initial thought was just to add/subtract the offset before displaying but it still didn't seem to work (I think due to getTimezoneOffset not adjusting for daylight savings?):

```
let date = new Date('2020-10-29 05:00')
console.log(new Date(date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + new Date().getTimezoneOffset())))
```

I suppose an alternate form of this question is: **Is there a way to parse a UTC datetime string as though it were local?**

Comment: getTimezoneOffset takes DST into account. But with `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` you would be looking at the offset from _today’s_ date - that might be different from the offset that was actually applicable on your date.

Comment: Hi @CBroe thanks but I don't think it matters as I just want the time to display exactly as it appears without being localized/adjusted for the browser's locale.

Comment: Of course it matters, when you want to parse your date by taking the local time zone offset into account. In a country that uses DST, that local time zone offset will be _different_, depending on whether your date falls into the summer or winter time.

Comment: Sorry, I mean (and do correct me if I am still misunderstanding), I was just getting the current timezone offset, and trying to add it to the date (eg: `getTimezoneOffset()` says we are 60 minutes ahead, so remove 60 minutes from the time and display - should equal out to the original time, no?)

Answer (score 0):

If the string is UTC, you should parse it as UTC and then do everything in UTC. I think the easiest way is to parse the string as UTC with your own function or library.

Also, given:

```
new Date('2020-10-29 05:00')
```

some browsers will return an invalid date (they treat it as a malformed version of the [supported format](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss).

Generally, using the built–in parser is strongly discouraged because of browser inconsistencies. Also, messing with timezone offsets can also lead to difficult to find issues (like when applying the offset causes the date to cross a DST boundary).

A simple function to do the job:

```js
function parseAsUTC(s) {
  let [y, m, d, H, M] = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(y, m-1, d, H, M));
}

let s = '2020-10-29 05:00';
console.log(parseAsUTC(s));
```

Comment: Thank you, completely correct about the issue with the browser inconsistencies. This is helpful and very close, but I suppose the issue is I need the input string parsed as though it were local, not UTC (to avoid any conversion when displayed) - it would be something along the lines of: Always show `2020-10-29 05:00` regardless of browser locale. In this solution, the date object is converted, in Germany, to `Date Thu Oct 29 2020 06:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)` and displays as one hour later.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit further - the CMS is, frustratingly, always parsing the given date object as though it is UTC (even though it ignores the timezone of the given object somehow). So whatever is provided, it adds or removes hours based on the browser's locale. So my goal is to pass it a date object that compensates for the browser's locale accordingly.

Comment: @waffl—Date objects don't have a timezone, they are inherently UTC. Host system settings (inappropriately named "locale") are only considered when parsing a string to create a Date object and when getting and setting values from non–UTC *get\** and *set\** methods. If you always want to show the same date and time regardless of settings, then do everything in UTC.